# How to load an entire HTML page from one website into another

Tags: ajax, azure, jsonp

I have been working on a website www.xyz.com which is hosted on some server. I have been loading forms & contents from www.abc.com using I Frame which is hosted on Azure. We have now decided not to use I Frames and to load the content from www.abc.com using Jquery AJAX. Now the abc.com is providing me the UI page fragment for my forms and contents from Azure blob storage in form of .html file or .txt file. If i try to do a normal AJAX call for the HTML or TXT file path, i can the see the content coming in the Response tab of that URL but the code does not enters the Success template and hence i am unable to modify or access the content.

Please suggest

Comment: you can user CURL (in case you can run php file)

Comment: No, its an aspx file and we are not using PHP anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Application Request Routing (ARR) for this. This is a module you can install in IIS which also works in Windows Azure.

The following image illustrates how ARR works. An incoming request is intercepted and based on a set of rules the request is forwarded (for you this will be to **xyz.com**) and the response is the served back to the user. Even though this illustration explains the principle with sub directories, it can also be applied on the full site.

[image]